# Is there an auto nice daemon for MacOS?

Tags: macos, performance

I'm wondering if there is something similar to auto nice daemon like  'ananicy' or 'and' on MacOS. Maybe there is some standard daemon that is already running and doing a similar job?

Sometimes my beefy laptop is lagging for absolutely no reason and it would be great to have more control over what is happening.

Comment: Are you wondering whether there is an auto nice daemon running, or where to get one from to install on macOS, or how to diagnose the performance issues you see on your laptop? Please edit the question to provide more focus.

Comment: @nohillside thanks for helping with this question! I've updated it to make you more happy )

Comment: You can renice manually, same as nix, but I've never really found user intervention guesses any better than the OS does.

Comment: @nohillside I think this is a very simple yes/no question. What kind of other details do you need?

Comment: @Tetsujin I definitely can renice manually, but I would prefer to automate this process using some tool, preferably an open-source one. Apple has financial incentives to make older laptops more laggy (or, more likely, ignore performance problems happening on slightly outdated machines), so it makes sense to have such a tool for the end user.

Comment: We are not Google :-) What kind of research have you done in terms of looking for such tools? Also, the question is in the review queue for reopening already, it may take a few days til enough high-rep users habe cast their vote.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app that does something like what you are looking for. It's not free, but it's not expensive. I've used it in the past and found it very effective at identifying apps that are eating CPU and giving you options to limit how much CPU they use.

It's from a long-time Mac developer (who also makes Default Folder X, which goes back to the pre-Mac OS X days) and has a free 15-day trial.

YMMV, of course, but I'd recommend it.

https://www.stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/

Comment: Brilliant. That developer is so good. Default Folder blew my mind when I first saw it work (back in the day).

Answer (score 0):

No, `nice` really hasn’t been an effective tool on OS X for 15 years or perhaps it was never a good scheduling tool.

However, there are many other tools to analyze performance metrics and specifics, [most of which get invoked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268720/5472) via `sysdiagnose`.

I hesitate to recommend any without knowing what major version of macOS is giving you concern and possibly what precisely “lagging” is and how you measure it.

Some tools are unchanged for a decade and others are adapted or less useful on Monterey and more recent OS:

- [Where are crash logs after a system freeze?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268658/)
- [How do you get system diagnostic files from macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59917/)
- [Tool for determining performance bottleneck](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95109/)